# How do I mock the @Attribute decorator string provider in an ng2 unit test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

I have a component that I'm unit testing, but I've run into a gotcha. I don't know how to mock the work of the @Attribute decorator in my test.

`Error: No provider for String!`

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(@Attribute("handle") private handle: string) { }
}
```

I specifically need to know what to 'provide' in my test.

`{ provide: ??, useValue: "" }`

**UPDATE**

Here's the test setup

```
describe("MyComponent", () => {
    let component: MyComponent;

    beforeEach(() => {
        this.injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
            { provide: ??, useValue: "" }, //@Attribute provider??
            ... // other mocked providers
            MyComponent
        ]);

        component = this.injector.get(MyComponent);
    });
    ...
});
```

Comment: why do you need to mock it?

Comment: @Maximus I'm not showing the entire component constructor. This is just one parameter of many. It's just that this one is causing me grief. Right now our unit tests use an injector to create our component we're testing, but we may need to break away from this pattern and manually create an instance of our component. I technically don't need to mock it. I just need a work around for my unit test to work.

Comment: Can you add code where you're creating this component?

Comment: @yurzui As requested, I've updated the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
{ provide: String, useValue: "test" },
AppComponent
```

the following will also work

```
import { Inject} from '@angular/core';

let token = 'handle';
Inject(token)(MyComponent, null, 0); // 0 is index of your parameter

let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
  { provide: token, useValue: "test" },
```

If you have multiple `string` params like

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(
    @Attribute("handle") private handle: string, 
    @Attribute("handle2") private handle2: string) {}
```

then you can write:

```
Inject('handle')(MyComponent, null, 0);
Inject('handle2')(MyComponent, null, 1);

let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
  { provide: 'handle', useValue: "test" },
  { provide: 'handle2', useValue: "test2" },
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/GWAaVwqmAs0Xp97zibU4?p=preview)**

Comment: This works! For bonus points, if I had multiple String params, would I then just use a factory for my string provider?